# Visual Studio 2017 can't pair to MacBook Pro for my Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

"unexpected error occurred while checking the SSH configuration of ' MacBook Pro'.

MacBook connected to Ethernet LAN IP 10.0.0.114
Clicked VS toolbar > Pair to Mac icon.
Add Mac...  entered 10.0.0.114
error:
"Couldn't retrieve SSH Fingerprint"

Project on same Windows 10 computer used to pair with same mac a few months ago.

Comment: You can have a try with forgetting this mac, and re-adding it.Also this can be related to network's quality of Mac or PC. You need to reboot computer .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the Internet Network (create a temp wifi hotspot from your phone) that both the devices are on and test it. It is likely that the Firewall settings of the internet changed within those few months.